# Calling remove(index) in the AChartEngine

Tags: java, android, achartengine

I'm having a problem with the AChartEngine library. Calling remove(index) on an instance of XYSeries gives an null pointer exception. It is odd as I know the series exists and has displayed the set count just before the crash.

```
public View addDataView(){

    int datasetCount = dataset.getSeriesAt(0).getItemCount();
    XYSeries seriesA = dataset.getSeriesAt(0);
    XYSeries seriesB = dataset.getSeriesAt(1);

    /** Enforce max data points on the displayed chart */
    if (datasetCount > maximumDataPoints - 1) {
        System.out.println("SizeOfSeries: "+seriesA.getItemCount());

        seriesA.remove(0);
        seriesB.remove(0);
            }

    //d.getTime() format: 1357120800000
    seriesA.add(new Date().getTime(), 20 + new Random().nextInt() % 100); // PR // TODO
    seriesB.add(new Date().getTime(), 20 + new Random().nextInt() % 100); // BO // TODO;

    dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    dataset.addSeries(seriesA);
    dataset.addSeries(seriesB);

    autoscroll();

    return ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(context, dataset, renderer, "`ss h:mm a");
}
```

Here is the associated logcat output:

```
01-04 14:16:31.806: I/System.out(25215): SizeOfSeries: 20
01-04 14:16:31.806: D/AndroidRuntime(25215): Shutting down VM
01-04 14:16:31.806: W/dalvikvm(25215): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410fa300)
01-04 14:16:31.806: E/AndroidRuntime(25215): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-04 14:16:31.806: E/AndroidRuntime(25215): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-04 14:16:31.806: E/AndroidRuntime(25215):    at org.achartengine.model.XYSeries.getY(XYSeries.java:169)
01-04 14:16:31.806: E/AndroidRuntime(25215):    at org.achartengine.model.XYSeries.initRange(XYSeries.java:83)
01-04 14:16:31.806: E/AndroidRuntime(25215):    at org.achartengine.model.XYSeries.remove(XYSeries.java:140)
01-04 14:16:31.806: E/AndroidRuntime(25215):    at charts.Chart.addDataView(Chart.java:75)
01-04 14:16:31.806: E/AndroidRuntime(25215):    at com.example.pml.PulseRateActivity$ChartThread.onProgressUpdate(PulseRateActivity.java:68)
01-04 14:16:31.806: E/AndroidRuntime(25215):    at com.example.pml.PulseRateActivity$ChartThread.onProgressUpdate(PulseRateActivity.java:1)
01-04 14:16:31.806: E/AndroidRuntime(25215):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:647)
01-04 14:16:31.806: E/AndroidRuntime(25215):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-04 14:16:31.806: E/AndroidRuntime(25215):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-04 14:16:31.806: E/AndroidRuntime(25215):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
01-04 14:16:31.806: E/AndroidRuntime(25215):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-04 14:16:31.806: E/AndroidRuntime(25215):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-04 14:16:31.806: E/AndroidRuntime(25215):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
01-04 14:16:31.806: E/AndroidRuntime(25215):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
01-04 14:16:31.806: E/AndroidRuntime(25215):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What version of the library are you using? Looking at the code in XYSeries, the exception doesn't make sense.

Comment: achartengine-1.0.0.jar, The latest version on the project page.

Comment: I suggest you try the 1.1.0-rc1 that is available for download here: http://www.achartengine.org/content/download.html

Comment: you're only displaying the count on the A series, not also B which could have 0 elements. add a System.out.println("SizeOfSeries: "+seriesB.getItemCount()); before the removal and see what's going on.

Comment: I assure you, the same operations are performed on both the A and B series.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
Initially the problem comes from initRange() if you remove a point which was a Max/Min.
But after commenting initRange I still get a null pointer on line 'double removedY = removedEntry.getValue();' of remove(). 
It looks like mXY.removeByIndex(index); returns an element with value set to null but I can't find out why.

I'm running on the last revision available on subversion.
It looks to me like some kind of race condition maybe since it doesn't fail always a the same time. I built a "sliding-window" loop in which I maintain a given number of constant points on the chart. In this example it's just 3, so after the 3rd point every time i add one I remove another.
At first logs look normal:

```
01-11 23:06:48.060: E/AChartGraph(2038): Added 1 item.  getIndexForKey: 0
01-11 23:06:48.060: E/AChartGraph(2038): series1.getItemCount(): 1
01-11 23:06:48.060: E/AChartGraph(2038): Added 1 item.  getIndexForKey: 1
01-11 23:06:48.060: E/AChartGraph(2038): series1.getItemCount(): 2
01-11 23:06:48.160: E/AChartGraph(2038): Added 1 item.  getIndexForKey: 2
01-11 23:06:48.160: E/AChartGraph(2038): series1.getItemCount(): 3
01-11 23:06:48.160: E/AChartGraph(2038): Removed item 0. series1.getItemCount(): 2
01-11 23:06:48.160: E/AChartGraph(2038): Added 1 item.  getIndexForKey: 2
01-11 23:06:48.160: E/AChartGraph(2038): series1.getItemCount(): 3
01-11 23:06:48.160: E/AChartGraph(2038): Removed item 0. series1.getItemCount(): 2
01-11 23:06:48.160: E/AChartGraph(2038): Added 1 item.  getIndexForKey: 2
01-11 23:06:48.160: E/AChartGraph(2038): series1.getItemCount(): 3
01-11 23:06:48.160: E/AChartGraph(2038): Removed item 0. series1.getItemCount(): 2
01-11 23:06:48.160: E/AChartGraph(2038): Added 1 item.  getIndexForKey: 2
01-11 23:06:48.160: E/AChartGraph(2038): series1.getItemCount(): 3
```

This goes on and on a bit until this happens:

```
01-11 23:06:55.300: E/AChartGraph(2038): Added 1 item.  getIndexForKey: 2
01-11 23:06:55.300: E/AChartGraph(2038): series1.getItemCount(): 3
01-11 23:06:55.300: E/AChartGraph(2038): Removed item 0. series1.getItemCount(): 2
01-11 23:06:55.300: E/AChartGraph(2038): Added 1 item.  getIndexForKey: 1
01-11 23:06:55.300: E/AChartGraph(2038): series1.getItemCount(): 2
01-11 23:06:55.300: E/AChartGraph(2038): Removed item 0. series1.getItemCount(): 1
01-11 23:06:55.300: E/AChartGraph(2038): Added 1 item.  getIndexForKey: 2
01-11 23:06:55.300: E/AChartGraph(2038): series1.getItemCount(): 2
01-11 23:06:55.300: W/dalvikvm(2038): threadid=14: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40bfb930)
01-11 23:06:55.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2038): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
01-11 23:06:55.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2038): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-11 23:06:55.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2038):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
01-11 23:06:55.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2038):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
01-11 23:06:55.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2038):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
01-11 23:06:55.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2038):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
01-11 23:06:55.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2038):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
01-11 23:06:55.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2038):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
01-11 23:06:55.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2038):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-11 23:06:55.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2038): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-11 23:06:55.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2038):     at org.achartengine.model.XYSeries.getY(XYSeries.java:169)
01-11 23:06:55.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2038):     at org.achartengine.model.XYSeries.initRange(XYSeries.java:83)
01-11 23:06:55.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2038):     at org.achartengine.model.XYSeries.remove(XYSeries.java:140)
01-11 23:06:55.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2038):     at com.mbev.android.Tmty.Helpers.AChartGraph.addAndPrune(AChartGraph.java:226)
01-11 23:06:55.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2038):     at com.mbev.android.Tmty.DashboardFragment$startUpdateTmtyThread.doInBackground(DashboardFragment.java:284)
01-11 23:06:55.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2038):     at com.mbev.android.Tmty.DashboardFragment$startUpdateTmtyThread.doInBackground(DashboardFragment.java:1)
01-11 23:06:55.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2038):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-11 23:06:55.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2038):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
01-11 23:06:55.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2038):     ... 3 more
```

Notice how suddenly the index for the added point is 1 instead of 2, and the itemCount goes down to 2 also, we've just lost a point!.
If we test this with more points it takes longer and we see logs in which we gradually start "loosing" points until it crashes on XYSeries.getY. I believe it is trying to remove one of those points which mysteriously disappeared earlier.

**EDIT 1:**
In this case I was plotting a time-series and the error came when I added 2 points with the same key (date in this case). **The remove function removes all points for a given key, not sure if it's intended or a bug though.** But it might well be the same error you have.